# Get URL fetched out of an AJAX in IFRAME / Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, google-chrome-extension

i have the following problem:

I want to create a chrome-extensions but have some serious problems:

I have a page where a iframe is loaded. This iframe has some JS code in it which would perform a some AJAX Magic. This AJAX Request returns a XML Document where I need a URL from.  This URL should be opened in  a new Tab. I don't know how to realise that easily. Reloading the Firstpage (with the IFRAME in it isn't posssible) and I have no influence on the page design.

IFRAME-Code on first page:

```
<iframe data-location="fullmiddle" class="main_tv_player" src="http://www.xyz.tv/***.html"></iframe>
```

AJAX on called page:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "//abc.tv/****",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function (data) {
   },
   error: function (response) {
      //alert('error');
   }
});
```

XML (or AJAX Response):

```
<data>
   <token 
   auth="aqaqaqaqaqaqaqa" 
   url="http://xcv.tv/***/master.***" status="0" statustext="success" comment="success"/>
</data>
```

Thanks for every answer !

Best regards from Frankfurt

Answer (score -1):

You can use window.open(url) inside success function

Comment: The Problem is that I shouldn't be able to insert code into the ajax Request due to the fact that this is inside of a iframe, so I would have to run the AJAX Request myself in the extension. But to do this I would need the URL of the "original" AJAX Request of the Iframe. Do you know a easy way of getting this ?